# What's the best way to delete elements from an object inside an iterator?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, loops

Suppose you want to delete an element from inside an iteration:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
for i = 0 to len(a){
    print a[i];
    if (i==1) a.remove(i);
};
```

The output is `a b d e`, with `c` missing. This is a common bug that happens because you changed the array while it was still looping. Some workarounds include keeping a list of elements to delete after the loop, and updating the index after a deletion. How do you deal with this problem?

Comment: use a library iterator and remove _through_ the iterator.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: In Java, that's `ArrayList#iterator()`. It has a `delete` method that can delete the current element.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious approach is to iterate from the end of the array to the beginning:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
for i = len(a)-1 downto 0 {
    print a[i];
    if (i==1) a.remove(i);
};
```

Many languages have iterators with support for deleting elements during forward iteration by telling the iterator to do the deletion. However, this does not always work (e.g., an iterator for the list returned by Java's `Arrays.asList` will not support deleting elements, because the list does not "own" the backing array.

If you have to forward iterate using an index, at least subtract 1 from the index when you delete the element. That way you won't skip elements.

Comment: How those languages implement it? That is, how they know you are going to delete an element inside the loop? Do they ask for you to return a specific token from the iterator? Do they check at each iteration if the array has changed?

Comment: @Dokkat - Typically they maintain a "current index" and adjust it as needed. Also quite commonly they will fail if more than one iterator is active at a time when an element is deleted. Some implementations do maintain a "modified count" that the iterator checks at each array access; it will often throw an exception if there was an out-of-band change to the array.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your iterator access -- including the loop, which in your example iterates from 0 to 5, even though position 5 may no longer exist by the end -- is by concrete position in the collection, or by abstract reference to the next element.

For instance, iterators in Java are of the abstract type, so you can delete the pointed-to item and then reliably continue iterating through the remainder of them.

In a language like C, when iterating through an array you would more typically encounter the difficulty you describe and risk writing buggy code.  Perhaps the best general solution is to accumulate the "to-delete" set of things which you want to delete, and then process them as a separate step.  Only if you have full knowledge to the internal representation of the collection and how iteration works can you safely perform the deletion and then adjust the iterator -- and the termination condition of the loop -- correctly to continue iterating.  This will, however, often by the case anyway if you are working with an array.  It's just a question of whether the additional adjustment code is simpler than the code to maintain the "to-delete" set.

Answer (score 0):

Your can delete it even inside an iteration via an iterator.

```
vector::iterator itVec = vectInt.begin();
for ( ; itVec != vectInt.end(); )
{
 if (*itVec == 1022) 
  itVec = vectInt.erase(itVect);
 else
  ++itVec;
}
```

the interator response to know the end of the elements (instead of via recording the length of the end), and free the memory.